# Sincronização Android x Web

Tags: android, api, aplicação-web, sincronização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que ira funcionar offline no `android` e sincronizar com uma versão `web`. Tenho uma `API` que ira intermediar essa sincronização.

Atualmente a versão `android` tem um `timestamp` para controlar as alterações no registro, e a ideia era na hora de sincronizar com a `API` verificar os registros com data de atualização maior que a data da ultima sincronização.

Porem a duvida é como controlar alterações no relógio do `android` pois o usuário pode estar com o horário ou data diferentes do correto. Assim poderia ocorrer de o horário do aparelho estar menor que o da ultima sincronização fazendo com que não envie os dados alterados.

Comment: Ao iniciar o app Android peça ao serviço web o seu UNIX DateTime, faça o mesmo com o do dispositivo android calcule a diferença e aplique-a para calcular o timestamp.

Comment: @ramaral tua resposta me parece correta, por que não posta como resposta, assim o Alisson pode aceitar como correta.

Comment: @TúlioF. Talvez não esteja completamente correcta porque só funciona se a app tiver acesso à internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) retorna quantos millisegundos se passaram desde a meia noite de 01/01/1970. O problema é que ele pode ser alterado pelo usuário ou a própria rede celular.

Sua aplicação pode detectar quando esse relógio for alterado ouvindo aos seguintes broadcasts:

- [ACTION_TIME_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED): Disparado toda vez que o relógio é alterado pelo usuário ou sistema.
- [ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED): Disparado toda vez que o fuso-horário é alterado.

O problema maior é que você não tem controle algum sobre o relógio do device, sabendo disso você pode pensar em uma lógica que atenda a sua necessidade, pode ser simples ou complexa.

### Uma alternativa

Em caso de o tempo não ser importante, ao invés de usar timestamp, por que não usar um número de versão? Isso elimina todos os problemas que um timestamp tem.

### Incremental

Pode ser **incremental**, seu servidor manda um número de versão, ex.: **1**, na próxima atualização **2** e por aí vai. A App compara a versão na hora de sincronizar, atualiza se estiver com um número menor que a do servidor.

### Identificador único

Ou pode ser um **identificador único**, como um GUID `java.util.UUID.randomUUID();`. Seu servidor manda esse guid. A App compara se o guid que ela tem é diferente da do servidor, atualiza se estiver diferente.

Comment: Túlio, eu já tinha resolvido este caso. Usei a opção do incremental.
Criei um campo que toda alteração que tiver ele é incrementado, assim consigo saber se houve alteração desde a ultima sincronização.

Comment: @AlissonMarqui nesse caso o SO estimula você a postar uma resposta a sua própria pergunta e aceitá-la como correta. De forma que outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida possam se beneficiar da solução que você encontrou.

Comment: Vou postar a resposta aqui. Obrigado.