# Como resolver uma sincronização com o servidor quando houver queda de conexão no Android?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo, onde tem um cadastro de empregos em SQLite que deve ser sincronizado com o servidor em PHP com Mysql.

Depois de pesquisar muito, não encontrei nenhuma resposta que resolve a minha dúvida.

Estou baseando minha sincronização no modo **Incremental** como sugere esta resposta.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146592/97220

Então por exemplo, quando o usuário finaliza o cadastro, o aplicativo insere os dados no Sqlite, e cria uma versão de dados, e ao mesmo tempo ja tenta se comunicar com o servidor para enviar os dados inseridos. Quando chega no servidor o PHP consulta se a versão é mais nova, e altera os dados e envia a resposta de conclusão pro aplicativo.

Assim como demonstro nessa animação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui está tudo ótimo e funcionando.

Agora o meu problema está no modo offline e quando cai a conexão no meio da sincronização.

Por exemplo. Eu cadastro um novo item, crio uma versão de dados no celular mesmo quando tiver offline. Ai quando conectar, preciso saber como o aplicativo detecta que ainda existe dados que não foi enviado.

E quando os dados são enviados, mas a conexão cai no meio do caminho. Como o meu aplicativo pode saber que ainda existe dados que precisam de resposta?

O problema seria mais ou menos como nessa animação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E, depois da queda, o aplicativo não poderá tentar inserir os dados novamente, pq a versão no servidor ja estará atualizada, e não retornará resposta de atualização.

Será que deu pra entender? Não sei se consegui explicar direito.

Meu problema está sendo com lógica para resolver quando acontece este tipo de erro.

Fico muito agradecida se alguém puder me dar uma luz sem me negativar. Não sei outro modo de fazer esta pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma verificação a cada X segundos/min/hora para verificar se há internet, e tudo que for feito você salva no seu **SQLite** e cria uma coluna que carrega o estado padrão de não sincronizado, quando essa linha for enviada, você muda o estado dela, quando o usuário modificar essa linha novamente, você muda o estado de novo para não sincronizado.

Para fazer essa verificação de tempos em tempos você pode usar:

```
Timer time = new Timer();
time.schedule(new Verifica(context), 0, intervalo_de_verificação);
```

Na classe você faz:

```
private class Verifica extends TimerTask{
    private Context context;

    public Verifica(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }

    @override
    public void run(){
       if(conect(context)){
            //Verifico o que mudou após a ultima verificação e mando pro servidor
       }else{
            //Salvo que ainda não tenho internet
       }
    }

    private boolean conect(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
        if (connMgr != null) {
            networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

No método que você faz o envio, você também pega a reposta do servidor e muda o estado no registro do **SQLite** pra mostrar que aquela linha já foi sincronizada, mas na hora que ela mudar, você muda novamente o estado para não sincronizado.

Além disso você pode usar o **BroadCast** ou um **Service** pra fazer essa verificação quando o aplicativo já estiver fechado e sincronizar antes da próxima vez que o usuário abrir o app.

Só uma coisa, o `Timer` só é cancelado se você fizer:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Ou se a aplicação morrer, caso contrário, mesmo com `onPause`/ `onStop` ela vai continuar rodando, é importante isso para não deixá-lo rodando em momentos que ele não é necessário.

No caso da sua pergunta, da conexão cair antes de receber a resposta que foi concretizada a atualização, você pode salvar numa tabela o que foi alterado, e na própria resposta dessa alteração vice por exemplo o id, e quando o app recebesse, ele mandava uma nova requisição falando "olha, já identifiquei que tudo deu certo" e exclui esse últimao registro, que é o que está esperando a resposta de volta do app.

Quando você vai verificar se tem Internet, se tudo der certo a primeira coisa que você faz é procurar se no seu servidor existe algum registro que esperava sua resposta e essa não foi concretizada. A partir daí você decide o que faz com os dados.

Comment: Obrigada pela ótima explicação. Não conhecia essa função de time.schedule. Mas uma última pergunta. Nesse caso se por exemplo der erro no celular e aplicação fechar, o timer será cancelado né, conforme você explicou. Então estou pensando em usar suas dicas, mas com service. Mas tenho medo de ser um problema pra ocupar muito a memória de usuários com aparelho mais antigo e fraco, ja que o service continua rodando mesmo com o aplicativo fechado. Minha pergunta é... Você tem alguma dica especial para usar service sem ocupar muita memoria, ou isso é só paranoia minha, e posso fazer tranquilamente?

Comment: @SamantaSilva eu acho mais paranoia, o `Service` vai só fazer o trabalho dele e depois disso você o mata, não vai deixá-lo rodando infinitamente, pra fazer essa verificação quando o app **NÃO** estiver aberto de tempos em tempos você pode usar um `AlarmManager`, que de tempo em tempo é ativado caso o app **NÃO** esteja aberto, você consegue configurar ele pra funcionar dessa forma, porque se com o app aberto você já usar o `timer`, não precisa do `Service` também, isso sim gastaria `memoria` a toa

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada pelas respostas. Me ajudou muito. Vou por em prática. Bjss